# Using arrays in 2 separate classes in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, dice

How do i use an array from my main in a different class. I'm making a game where I need to have a single die roll three times. I then take each value and make comparisons like do 2/3 numbers match. if then add to 12 then give the player the pot back.
This is the class where i want to use the info from the array. I learnt about arrays and loops last night so i dont really know what im doing

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

private double Bet;
private double Pot;
private double TotalPot;

public void Pot( ){
Pot = 50;
}
public void inputBet( ) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the current month in numerical format: ");
    Bet = keyboard.nextDouble();
    if (Bet <= Pot) {
        System.out.println("Error, Bet out of range");

        inputBet();
    }
    else if (Bet == 0) {
        System.out.println("Thank you for playing");
    }
}

public void inputEnd( ){

}

public void removeBet( ){
    TotalPot = Bet - Pot;
}
public void dieComparison1(){
if ((die[0] == die[1]) || (die[0] == die[2])){
    TotalPot = (Bet * 2) + Pot;
    }
}
public void print(){
System.out.println(+ TotalPot);}
}
```

This is my main where the array is created.

```
public class Assign3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Game smith = new Game();
    //smith.Pot();
    //smith.inputBet();
    int[] die = new int[3];
     Die bob = new Die();
     int total = 0;
     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        die[i] = bob.rollDie();
        bob.displayDie(die[i]);
        total = total + die[i];
     }
     bob.displayDie(total);


}
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear: from  `main()` you're calling to methods such as `rollDie()` and `displayDie()` but you don't show us their implementations. Further, you don't explain what is it that you're trying to achieve, what's the role of Arrays in it and etc.

Comment: Your `inputBet` Method asks the user to *"Please enter the current month in numerical format: "* but the input takes the bets. Have you copied the code from somewhere and trying to modify it to achieve the desired results of your program?

Comment: If you are trying to get the die array into the Game class somehow that is pretty simple. Try something like this:
`Game game = new Game(die);`
Where Game constructor looks like this:
`public Game(int[] dieArray) {}`
Make sense?

Comment: The main creates four values. Three separate die rolls and then a total at the end. I need to be able to "isolate" the three values (die rolls) it prints out individually so I can make several "if" statements based on the die rolls. In the Game class I have a method called die comparison where i tried to use the values from the main but it wont recognize the three separate die. Theres also a Die class where it generates a number from 1-6 that i didnt post here

Comment: Yeah i just coppied the keyboard code from an old project and havent changed the system.out message yet @blip

Comment: What is the relation between your `Game` class and `Assign3` class? you have not used the `Game` in your `Assign3` class.

Comment: my assign3 class is the main. Im trying to use the loop/array in assign3 in the game call @blip

Comment: Class**   @Blip I dont know if you were tagged in the comment above^

Comment: Yes I was tagged on all the above comments whether you *B* or *b* as the first letter. Now the point is why are you not using the `main` method to create an instance of `Game` class and then put the rolling of dies in the `Game` class itself?

Comment: @blip I dont know what that means. Ive been programming for a month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above code you have posted you in the `main` method your have commented out lines where you had created an instance of `Game` class:

```
//Game smith = new Game();
//smith.Pot();
//smith.inputBet();
```

as you have first created an instance of `Game` and stored it in variable `smith` and then you called the methods `Pot` and `inputBet` methods on `smith` variable, you could declare another method in the `Game` class say `rollDie` to contain the code that you have for the rolling of the die and called it as `smith.rollDie()` from your `main` method. This would eliminate the requirement of having the array `die` that you have created in the `main` to be accessed from the `Game` class.

What I mean to say by the above is:

1. First your create a variable `die` of type `int[]` in your `Game` class and initialise it to a size of three as:

   ```
   private int[] die = new int[3];
   ```
2. you crate a method say `rollDie()` method containing the methods of rolling the die as :

   ```
   public void rollDie(){
       Die bob = new Die();
       int total = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
           die[i] = bob.rollDie();
           bob.displayDie(die[i]);
           total = total + die[i];
       }
       bob.displayDie(total);
   }
   ```
3. Now in your `main` method comment all that is not commented and uncomment all that is commented. Then add the line `smith.rollDie()` to roll the die and get the results as :

   ```
   Game smith = new Game();
   smith.Pot();
   smith.inputBet();
   smith.rollDie();
   // Here call the other method that are required to play the game like `dieComparision1()` etc.
   /*int[] die = new int[3];
   Die bob = new Die();
   int total = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      die[i] = bob.rollDie();
      bob.displayDie(die[i]);
      total = total + die[i];
   }
   bob.displayDie(total);*/
   ```